# Adwords API : how to create adgroup and it's keywords in one request

Tags: php, google-ads-api

From adwords php library example, I understand that I have to

1. get campaigns using "CampaignService"
2. then create an adgroup using "AdGroupService"
3. using above adgroup id, create keywordsvia "AdGroupCriterionService"
4. and finally create a text ad using "AdGroupAdService"

But above process require 4 requests. Is there a way to combine 2,3,4 and make a single request and get the final result?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this question when I was putting the same process together for my app. It's an odd one because there's a lot of backwards and forwards required for an outcome that is essentially quite simple.

The point is that you don't know your new AdGroup ID until stage 3, and as you've pointed out you need that to use the AdGroupCriterionService.

I don't have answer to your question, just letting you know that we're been thinking alike!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

nope, there is no way to do this in a single request. What you can do is request for premium access so you don't have requests limit.

btw: if you figure out any way to do that in a single request please do update the subject as it would be interesting to know how (though not possible as far as I know so far)